# Double value with two decimals and a round on last number

Tags: java, rounding, talend

I have some double values like

```
3.1795926
25.549000
11.11004
```

My goal is to get

```
3.20
25.55
11.10
```

If I use the function `Mathematical.FFIX(3.1795926,2)` I can get it to two decimals like I want, but it don't round as I want to. It gives me `3.18`.

How can i do this?

Comment: Please explain the reasoning behind having 3.1795926 round to 3.20 but 25.549 round to to 25.55.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using? Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Im working with Talend open Studio. Scott 3.18 is closer to 3.20 then 3.15. If i get 3.12 i Need to make it 3.10 and if ist 3.13 it has to be 3.15 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
double d = 25.549000;
d = 0.05*(Math.round(d/0.05));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like following

```
double value = 3.1795926;
(double)Math.round(value * 100) / 100
```

That is for 2 digits precision.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.